# Скорость копирования результата SQL запроса MySQL (copy to clipboard)

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть вот такой запрос

```
    SELECT sms.*,
       clel.date_triggered,
       clel.campaign_id,
       clel.channel_id,
       clel.event_id
FROM (
    SELECT sms.lead_id,
           sms.date_sent,
           sms.sms_id,
           sms.source,
           sms.source_id
    FROM sms_message_stats sms
    USE INDEX (sms_message_stats_date_sent_idx)
    WHERE DATE(sms.date_sent) BETWEEN '2023-10-26' AND '2023-10-27'
) AS sms
LEFT JOIN campaign_lead_event_log clel
    ON sms.lead_id = clel.lead_id
    AND clel.channel_id = sms.sms_id
    AND sms.date_sent >= clel.date_triggered
    AND sms.date_sent < (
        SELECT CASE WHEN MIN(clel2.date_triggered) IS NULL THEN NOW()
                    ELSE MIN(clel2.date_triggered)
               END
        FROM campaign_lead_event_log clel2
        WHERE clel.lead_id = clel2.lead_id
        AND clel2.channel_id = clel.channel_id
        AND clel2.date_triggered > clel.date_triggered
    );
```

Выполняется за пару секунд, но именно копирование в буфер происходит очень долго. Похожие запросы с большим кол-во строк и столбов копируются намного быстрее.
Я заметил что последний блок с подзапросом играет большую роль на скорость, но у брать его возможности нет.
С индексами игрался, особо не помогает, может есть идеи как его оптимизировать? Использую DataGrip.

Comment: Не, а какое отношение эта проблема имеет к MySQL? Копирование происходит из клиента в буфер ОС, когда MySQL уже полностью выполнил свою часть работы и отдыхает...

Comment: Хорошо, что сделать что бы ускорить этот процесс, и что на него влияет? И почему другие запросы у которых результат в сотни раз больше копируют в сотни раз быстрее.

Comment: Не, это вообще как? "Есть какой-то (но я не скажу какой) клиент, из которого данные долго копируются в буфер обмена, чё делать?" - неужели сам не понимаешь, насколько плохо задан вопрос? Прям "у меня в подполе происходит стук" (с).

Comment: Прошу прощения. Использую DataGrip.

Comment: Некоторые клиенты могут "модифицировать" запросы и ответы в части количества возвращающихся строк, что бы как можно быстрее показать вам результат. Когда вы жмете копировать, клиент начнет вычитывать все данные из бд, а вот тут как раз может быть задержка по времени. БД продолжает вычитывать данные, хотя визуально для вас запрос уже завершен. Да и у вас сам запрос предполагает вычитку всей таблицы. Так что, с большой долей вероятности, проблема не в объеме данных, а в реальном времени выполнения запроса.

Comment: боюсь у вас там условие  `WHERE DATE(sms.date_sent)` убивает все намеки на использвоание `USE INDEX (sms_message_stats_date_sent_idx)`. Уберите `DATE()` и напишите условия с `00:00:00` до `23:59:59` и хинт скорее всего не понадобится (если предполагаем что у вас в это индексе поле `datetime` стоит первым столбцом). собственно какого то смысла пихать тут "подзапрос" (делать производную таблицу) в `from ... as sms` нет